# Как правильно переименовать несколько файлов?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, как правильно определить папку в `x32/x64` системах, проверить наличие файлов, и переименовать их?

```
    private void RenameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\MyApp")) == true)
        {
            if (File.Exists(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\MyApp\\testOriginal1.txt")) & (File.Exists(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\MyApp\\testOriginal2.txt"))))
            {
                File.Move(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\MyApp\\testOriginal1.txt"), Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\MyApp\\testRename1.txt"));
                File.Move(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\MyApp\\testOriginal2.txt"), Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\MyApp\\testRename2.txt"));
            }
        }
        else if (Directory.Exists(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\MyApp")) == false)
        {
            if (File.Exists(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles%\\MyApp\\testOriginal1.txt")) & (File.Exists(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles%\\MyApp\\testOriginal2.txt"))))
            {
                File.Move(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles%\\MyApp\\testOriginal1.txt"), Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles%\\MyApp\\testRename1.txt"));
                File.Move(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles%\\MyApp\\testOriginal2.txt"), Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles%\\MyApp\\testRename2.txt"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Обнаружил, что коду не хватает определения уже переименованных файлов, т.е. если файлы `testRename1.txt` и `testRename2.txt` присутствуют, приложение выдает ошибку...

Comment: Методов для проверки существования файлов вы знаете, в чем проблема?

Comment: Многовато `if (File.Exists...` и думаю `else if` можно было упростить до `else`, как считаете?

Comment: Упростите. Вы не знаете как вам отрефакторить код что бы он был более читаем или что? Так напишите об этом в вопросе. В чем суть вопроса-то?

Comment: Я так и не понял, чего вы хотите добиться, "Обнаружил, что коду не хватает определения уже переименованных файлов, т.е. если файлы testRename1.txt и testRename2.txt присутствуют, приложение выдает ошибку...", если у вас в коде жестко зашиты эти имена, то чего вы хотите получить кроме того, что имеете?

Comment: Вот эти операции `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%)` нужно делать в строковые переменные, до всяких ифов, а потом уже использовать эти переменные в условиях.

Comment: `Directory.Exists(ПутьКПапке)` уже отдает `true` или `false`, поэтому это `... == true` делать не нужно.

Comment: Вы делаете что-то странное. Какая ваша реальная задача?

Comment: Что странного? Попасть в папку приложения, и изменить имена двум файлам. Но сделать это нужно используя переменные, чтобы определить системный диск, и присутствие папки `x86` для систем где она есть, и для систем где ее нет. Поэтому все так муторно получается.

Comment: @Bulson не могли бы Вы, показать, как примерно, поместить `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%)` в строковые переменные? Это и нужно для упрощения кода, т.к. он слишком часто повторяет одно и тоже.

Comment: Вам в ответ написать на вопрос написать?

Comment: Да, если Вас не затруднит, Ваш предложенный вариант будет правильнее.

Comment: Хорошо, подождите...

Comment: Внезапно, но 'Попасть в папку приложения' может оказаться "а её установили не в Program files, а в D:\app\" и нужно вообще думать не о том, как правильного угадать разрядность папки ProgramFiles, а о том, что скрывается за термином "папка в которую установлена программа".

Comment: Для этого будет использоваться `FolderBrowserDialog`, если путь не будет найден, кнопка перейдет в состояние `RenameButton.Enabled = false;`, об этом тоже готовлю вопрос...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не проверял работу, но такой вот вариант

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string win32Path;
    string win64Path;
    TryGetPathes(out win32Path, out win64Path);

    string appNameDir = "MyApp";
    string oldName = "testOriginal";
    string newName = "testRename";

    if (win64Path.Length > 0)
    {
        RenameFile(win64Path, oldName, newName);
    }
    else
    {
        RenameFile(win32Path, oldName, newName);
    }
}



private static void TryGetPathes(out string win32Path, out string win64Path)
{
    win32Path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles%");

    //если системная переменная не существуюет, то будет выдана ошибка (см. документацию)
    try
    {
        win64Path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        win64Path = String.Empty;
    }

}

private static void RenameFile(string winPath, string oldName, string newName)
{
    string oldFile1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(winPath,
                                        String.Concat(oldName, "1", ".txt"));
    string newFile1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(winPath,
                                        String.Concat(newName, "1", ".txt"));

    string oldFile2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(winPath,
                                        String.Concat(oldName, "2", ".txt"));
    string newFile2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(winPath,
                                            String.Concat(newName, "2", ".txt"));

    try
    {
        System.IO.File.Move(oldFile1, newFile1);
        System.IO.File.Move(oldFile2, newFile2);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Ошибка с файлами: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Только опубликовал и заметил ошибку :) в метод `RenameFile()` надо еще передавать название папки программы `appNameDir` ну и прибавлять его к пути к файлу.

Comment: Спасибо, есть над чем подумать :)

Comment: Да, всегда пожалуйста.